# For a dependent categorical variable regressed on continuous variables, how bad is it to do linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

Suppose I have a categorical variable $Y$ that takes on three levels, $1,2,3$ and I am regressing it on $X$, which takes values in $\mathbb{R}$.

I understand that normally multinomial regression would handle this well. However, I am wondering just how bad it is to use linear regression in this case. It appears I am able to predict rather well -- is there a caveat here? Thanks!

Comment: If you ciould indicate your results and data , response  can be better. A few statements and assertios are self-styled and conflicting .please specify you goal' what is your model.

Comment: Have you used any diagnostics test after the analysis to see whether the assumptions are violated or not?

Comment: It will be useful if you could inform how many are your independent variables and kindly affirm whether the categorical variable is your dependent variable ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be more or less fine, or you might get absolute garbage.

It REALLY depends on what values "1" "2" and "3" in your dependent variable represent.

An OLS/linear regression tells you the association between a one unit increase in each independent variable and an "increase" in the dependent variable.

So the question you have to ask is "does it make sense to talk about the dependent variable 'increasing' or not?"

If the DV is a measure of socio economic status and 1,2, and 3 stand for "poor" "middle class" and "rich" then it makes sense to ask what factors are associated with having a "higher" value. So running a linear regression/OLS will do an OK job of that. Technically you are violating a bunch of other OLS assumptions, and if you are worried about that you could run an ordered logit. But OLS will probably give you the correct "story" in terms of signs and significance values.

However, if the DV is a measure of employment status and 1, 2 and 3 stand for "unemployed," "employed," and "retired," then it doesn't make any sense at all to ask what factors are associated with having a "higher" value. Running an OLS model (or even an ordered logit) on this dependent variable will give you garbage. To analyze this variable you need to either use a multinomial logit model, or recode the variable in some way (e.g. to a binary variable of some sort).

The model itself is blind to the distinction between these two types of variables, so there is no "test" you could run to sort it out. You need to use your own background knowledge about what Y is measuring.

And just as an aside - the measurement level of the INDEPENDENT variables are irrelevant when it comes to what type of model to choose. No matter whether you are running a binary logit, OLS, multinomial logit, or some other kind of model you've never heard of, the rules about what sorts of independent variables you can or can not include are the same.

Answer (score 0):

At least two concerns come to mind.

1. If you do not model with a multinomial distribution, you lose an obvious interpretation in terms of the probability of category membership. You don't get predictions that are exactly $1$, $2$, or $3$, so what do you do with a prediction like $1.2?$ Sure, you could round to the nearest integer, but this presents a few problems. First, the rounding means that the space of predictions that get mapped to categories $1$ and $3$ are $(-\infty, 1.5)$ and $[2.5,+\infty)$, respectively, yet the space of predictions that get mapped to category $2$ is $[1.5,2.5]$. You might be willing to make some distribution assumptions to alleviate this concern, but it sure seems like there is a lot more opportunity to be in the zones for categories $1$ and $3$ than to be in the zone for category $2$. Second, there is no sense of how costly the mistakes are. If you really need to be sure that a case is in category $2$ in order to classify that way, you might not want to round to $2$ unless the prediction is in the interval $(1.95, 2.2)$. Calibrated probabilities of class membership like you would be pursuing with a multinomial regression approach give a much more natural interpretation of the predictions.
2. It seems that, at low values of $X$, category $1$ is most likely; then category $2$ is most likely for medium values of $X$; finally, category $3$ is most likely for high values of $X$. (Maybe the order is reversed.) It is convenient that your categories were coded this way, but they just as easily could have been coded in a different order, which would wreck this monotonic relationship and not be detected as well by a linear model. Sure, you could use nonlinear basis functions like polynomials or splines, but imagine doing this when you have ten or a hundred categories that you have to put in the right order for each feature. That is just for one feature. If you have multiple features, you have to get the order right on all of them, and this is not a given. It might be that, on one feature, high values correspond with category $3$, medium values correspond with category $2$, and low values correspond with category $1$, yet another feature has high values that correspond with category $3$, medium values that correspond with category $1$, and low values that correspond with category $2$. No matter how you order the category labels, they will be incorrect for one of those features (and I will venture a guess that you have more than just two features).

If you can validate your ability to consistently get quality performance, perhaps it makes business to go with your modeling approach. However, given that multinomial modeling is not especially difficult to implement, the above caveats are worth considering.